# Java xml parsing. Navigating deep inside in a xml file with one function call

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have the following xml file

```
<basicCallInformation>
   <chargeableSubscriber>
       <simChargeableSubscriber>
           <imsi>26 20 32 23 16 62 80 3F</imsi>
           <msisdn>49 16 32 70 04 00</msisdn>
       </simChargeableSubscriber>
   </chargeableSubscriber>
</basicCallInformation>
```

I would like to go directly to the nodes "imsi" and "msisdn" to obtain their values with one function call if possible. Something like this

```
basicCallInformationNode.getNode('chargeableSubscriber/simChargeableSubscriber/imsi'); //something like this can be done in PLSQL
```

Is there a way to do that in Java? any workaround?

P.S. I am using DOM parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

```
        XPath.evaluate(
    "/basicCallInformation/chargeableSubscriber/simChargeableSubscriber/imsi |
     /basicCallInformation/chargeableSubscriber/simChargeableSubscriber/msisdn"
        );
```